# Open application on current screen when using multiple monitors

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, workspaces

Currently, I have two monitors that expand my workspace, one native from my laptop, that I use to control some applications (Spotify, Google Meets), and the other is external, which is used for general purposes (coding, watching videos). The problem is that it seems random on which monitor each application window will spawn when I start them (e.g. VSCode opening on the secondary monitor when opened on the primary). I've tried using CompizConfig, but it seems that the changes don't take effect, therefore I've uninstalled it since I may be doing something wrong or my Operational System doesn't support it. Does anyone have a solution for this or any application that can help to manage multiple monitors (e.g. set topbar on the secondary screen, handle OS's workspaces on different screens)?

My Ubuntu version is 18.04.5 LTS (Desktop Environment: GNOME) and its display mode is set to "Join Displays".

Comment: Are you using Compiz? This is not standard. Mention the desktop environment you are  using because this may and will depend on that.

Comment: You may be able to use tools such as `wmctrl` and/or `xdotool` with custom scripts/shortcuts to start applications and then automatically move/resize the windows as you want. See the respective `man` pages for details. I don't do it myself exactly but use `wmctrl` with hotkeys to focus a particular application windows, and `xdotool` to emulate certain keypresses with a touchscreen.

Comment: @vanadium I've updated the post for clarity.

Comment: @codlord But I will need to press on my keyboard to move the window? I would like a solution that could open an application on the monitor that my current mouse cursor is located or something like that.